# Reference request: a more complete "faster factorization into coprimes"

Tags: ds.algorithms, factoring, nt.number-theory

Some months ago, before the advent of "CS-Theory", I asked [a question on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23717/reference-request-given-a-divisor-d-of-n-how-quickly-can-i-obtain-the-largest-f) about efficiently factoring an integer *N* into coprime factors *n*<sub>1</sub> and *n*<sub>2</sub>, where *n*<sub>1</sub> is a multiple of a given a factor *d* of *N*.

[One of the answers](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23717/reference-request-given-a-divisor-d-of-n-how-quickly-can-i-obtain-the-largest-f/23728#23728) pointed me to [Dan Bernstein's website](http://cr.yp.to/coprimes.html), which has notes on obtaining a coprime base for a set of integers (and algorithms which work in more general settings than integers). For a set *S* of integers, a *coprime base* cb(*S*) is a set of integers which are coprime to one another, such that each element of *S* factors (uniquely) as a product of elements of cb(*S*). Bernstein's site has

1. An article dating from 1998, about constructing a coprime base in "essentially linear time", which is to say time  n log (n)<sup>O(1)</sup>  (where n is the number of input bits, or equivalently the logarithm of the product of the input set) and;
2. A draft manuscript from 2004 (which announces its own preliminariness), on "faster factorization into coprimes", which gives a sketch of how to compute a coprime base in time  n log (n)<sup>2+o(1)</sup> .

After a search for a "more complete" version of the second, or follow-up work by others, I was unable to find much more than links to one or the other of these articles, and slide-show presentations which again point to these articles.

**Question.** Has there been any more development of the ideas of "[Faster factorization into coprimes](http://cr.yp.to/lineartime/dcba2-20041103.pdf)" — possibly by different authors — into a finished article with the run-time as described above? Or is this accepted by the community as essentially complete?

(*Edit:* as I've now noted in the comments, Dan Bernstein himself says that he has not yet finished his results. But I'm still interested in finished results by others with comparable run-times, possibly for special cases, but only over the integers.)

Comment: [Just a suggestion] You can contact the author (Bernstein) and ask him, as well.

Comment: @Sadeq: that would be the obvious, direct approach, now wouldn't it? Let me give that a try.

Comment: Dan responded today, saying that he hasn't taken the time to finish the writeup yet. So it would seem that in the general case, there is not yet a complete version available by the original author.